# What are the different ways of matrix-vector multiplication when the matrix has the given form?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition

Suppose we have 
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
a & b \\
b & a
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
c \\
d
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
ac+bd \\
bc+ad
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Where $a,b,c,d$ are non-zero integers.

What are the different ways of performing matrix-vector multiplication of this form with less than 4 products?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First note that
$$ac+bd=ac+bd+bc-bc$$
$$=b(d-c)+c(a+b)$$
And
$$bc+ad=bc+ad+ac-ac$$
$$=a(d-c)+c(a+b)$$
So now we only need three products
$$A=a(d-c)$$
$$B=b(d-c)$$
$$C=c(a+b)$$
Therefore
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
a & b \\
b & a
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
c \\
d
\end{bmatrix}
=\begin{bmatrix}
ac+bd\\
bc+ad\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
$$
=
\begin{bmatrix}
b(d-c)+c(a+b)\\
a(d-c)+c(a+b)
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
B+C\\
A+C
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Answer (score 1):

You can go with three multiplications, compute 
$$ A := ac, B := bd, C := (a+b)(c+d) $$
then $$ \begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ b & a \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} c \\ d \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} A + B \\ C - A - B \end{bmatrix} $$